# How can we apply different formats to different columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In saw a question here on SO about applying different kinds of formatting to different columns in a dataframe.  The user's solution looked like this.

```
format_dollar = "${0:.2f}".format
format_percent = "{0:.2f}%".format

df_agg[['YTD Open', 'REV2', 'Real_Profit']] = df_agg[['YTD Open', 'REV2', 'Real_Profit']].applymap(format_dollar)
df_agg[['Percent_Profit']] = df_agg[['Percent_Profit']].applymap(format_percent)

df_agg.tail()
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

I want to format three specific columns something like this `$1,000,000.00` and I want to format one specific column like this `120.50%`.  I feel like Pandas should have something built-in just for this, but after Googling for a bit, I didn't come across anything useful.  Is there an easy way to do what I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in question arises if the data contains numbers formatted as string. You just need to convert the data type to float first and then apply the mapping.

```
df_agg[['YTD Open', 'REV2', 'Real_Profit']] = df_agg[['YTD Open', 'REV2', 'Real_Profit']].astype(float).applymap(format_dollar)
df_agg[['Percent_Profit']] = df_agg[['Percent_Profit']].astype(float).applymap(format_percent)
```

Comment: One more thing...how can I multiply the 'Percent_Profit' column by 100?

Comment: df_agg[['Percent_Profit']] = df_agg[['Percent_Profit']].astype(float).multiply(100).applymap(format_percent)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the column to numeric first

```
df_agg['Percent_Profit'] = pd.to_numberic(df_agg['Percent_Profit']).applymap(format_percent)
```